# Is it possible to have children routes and route-views in vuepress?

Tags: nested, vue-router, children, vuepress

I'm trying to have a children route-view inside my main page, and can't find a way to accomplish this in vuepress.

This is how I would normally accomplish this in Vue, in router.js

```
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/work/:worktitle',
                    name: 'workpage',
                    // component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/WorkView.vue'),

                    component: WorkView,
                    props: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

But I don't know where can I put such code in vuepress. (no router.js)

I am trying to accomplish this because I'm trying to have a collection of links in my homepage, and when clicked, I'd like to have the pages of those links rendered as a modal without going to a new page. But I'd like to retain the ability to link directly to these modals.

Answer (score 0):

use [`.vuepress/enhanceApp.js`](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/basic-config.html#app-level-enhancements) with [`router.addRoutes`](https://router.vuejs.org/zh/api/#router-addroutes)

```js
// async function is also supported, too
export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData, // site metadata
  isServer // is this enhancement applied in server-rendering or client
}) => {
  // ...apply enhancements to the app
  router.addRoutes([
    // ...
  ])
}
```